# SSH into machine, check to see if file exists, then fail Jenkins Execute shell if it does

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to SSH into a machine from a Jenkins Execute shell, check to see if a file exists on the machine and if it does then fail the shell. I have the following code however I can seem to get Jenkins to recognize that the output of echo is "yes" or no"
Please let me know what you think...

```
sshpass -p ${ServerNodePw} ssh -T -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${ServerNodeUser}@${ServerNodeIP} << EOSSH

(ls /Volumes/ServerHD/Users/username/Desktop/JenkinsVMbuild.lock && echo yes) || echo no
2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
echo "$?"
if [ "$?" = yes ]
then
  echo "File found"
  exit 1
  currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
else
  echo "File not found"
fi

EOSSH
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$?` is the exit status of the last executed command (or pipeline). In your case, it would always expand to `0`.

You can use command substitution instead if you want to store the echoed string in a variable.

You will also need to properly escape (or quote) the script in your here document. Otherwise `$var` will be substituted by *the caller* before passing the script to `ssh`.